# Combining a GPS bearing with your compass direction in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gps, transform, magnetometer

Swift 4 iOS 11.x

Running this code ... to get the GPS bearing and looking to combine it with my compass setting.

```
func getBearing(toPoint point: CLLocationCoordinate2D, longitude:Double, latitude: Double) -> Double {
    func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double { return degrees * Double.pi / 180.0 }
    func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double { return radians * 180.0 / Double.pi }

    let lat1 = degreesToRadians(degrees: latitude)
    let lon1 = degreesToRadians(degrees: longitude)

    let lat2 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point.latitude);
    let lon2 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point.longitude);

    let dLon = lon2 - lon1;

    let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    let x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
    let radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

    return radiansBearing
}
```

To get a value in radians I need to head ..

```
angle2U = self.getBearing(toPoint: goFigure, longitude:  (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, latitude:  (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
```

Then this code to use it to transform an image and give me a direction relative to the way I am pointing. I use the value I get from this angle2U in this call ...

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading heading: CLHeading) {

direction2G = CGFloat(heading.magneticHeading * Double.pi/180)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let direction2GN = CGFloat(self.angle2U) - direction2G
  let tr2 = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: direction2GN)
  self.degreeAngle.text = String(describing: direction2GN)
  self.directionImage.transform = tr2
}
```

Which works I think, but I want to check with somebody out there who knows what he/she is doing, since I got this at least in part from trial and error and I am not certain of the math.

Comment: Have you tried this on a device and verified that the results look reasonable? Are there any specific edge cases or scenarios that you want to ask about?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my iPad and it looked ok. But I am here. Latitude‎: ‎46.519962 DMS Lat‎: ‎46° 31' 11.8632'' N
Longitude‎: ‎6.633597 DMS Long‎: ‎6° 38' 0.9492'' E and I would like to test it in the southern hemisphere ideally. Does the math in the meantime look reasonable?